# How to simulate the UIPrerenderedIcon feature in a custom image

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

I have an IOS app in which a custom image is loaded in a view. I want the image to have
the same look and feel, the glossyness, roundness that we find on the Iphone/Ipad home screen
for different apps.

How can I get that effect for a custom image ? Is there any api for that ?